# Regular expression for dividing country calling codes

Tags: regex

I have a list of calling codes for all countries(the phone number prefixes), I would like to split them up in the 
country name and the actual code so I can put then into an xml.

I have tried back and forth but can not get a regexp going that takes all cases into account.
I think it is fairly simple for someone with a bit of experience.

The codes have these formats:

> Afghanistan 93
>   Anguilla 1 264
>   Antarctica 6721
>   Antigua and Barbuda 1 268
>   Bosnia and Herzegovina 387
>   Canada 1
>   Congo, Republic of the 242
>   Cote d'Ivoire 225
>   Ireland (Eire) 353
>   United States of America 1

There are around 235 of them in total, but these are the regulars and the exceptions.

```
^[a-zA-Z]\s,'()] for between 1 and X words and then it is [0-9\s]{1,5}$ for the numbers:

X
XX
XXX
XXXX
X XXX
```

So if I should express it as a sentence it would be: "from beginning of a line, take all characters (1) including space,'() until you encounter digits, then take all of these including space(2) until you encounter a line break."

I am using TextMate, and the docs says:

> TextMate uses the Oniguruma regular
>   expression library by K. Kosako.

I would appreciate any help given:)
Thank you.

Comment: Since you're on OS X (TextMate...) I recommend using Regexhibit ( http://homepage.mac.com/roger_jolly/software/#regexhibit ) to create regular expressions if you're new to them

Comment: Hi Pieter and thank you.
Regexhibit is downloading as I type this. It had me at "Having trouble getting your regular expressions just right? Not sure what they match and what they leave out? Tired of having to write test programs every time? RegExhibit can help." :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [posix regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions) should be sufficient: `^[a-zA-Z ]+[0-9 ]+$`

Comment: Hi soulmerge and thank you so much!
That was fast:) makes my last 1.5 hour seem pretty wasted.
It ended up like this:

find: 
^([a-zA-Z ]+)([0-9 ]+)$

replace:
<key>$2</key>
<string>$1</string>

Works like a charm.